# Group multiple arrays based on one common attributes with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have multiple arrays consist of people with different attributes for them. Something like

```
r[0] = {name: "john", phone: 123, industry: "food" }
r[1] = {name: "moe", phone: 333, industry: "feed"}
r[2] = {name: "mark", phone: 222, industry: "food"}
r[i] = ...
```

how can I loop through this array using javascript and then sort the result as arrays common attribute, let say industry, so that the result would be like

```
food[["john", 123],["mark", 222]] 

feed[["mark", 333]]
```

for now I can have the results like

```
food[["john", 123]]

feed[["moe", 333]]

food[["mark", 222]]
```

Comment: Please, format your "result" as an **array**, an **object** or a nested mix of them. Right now, this "result" you want makes no sense, it's just text with line breaks.

Comment: Thanks for your edit, but that **is still not an array**. By the way, just a tip: unless `john`, `food` etc are variables, it has to be "john", "food" etc...

Comment: @GerardoFurtado, can you please edit the array part you mean. I don't get your point

Comment: Of course I cant! You are the OP, only you can say what you want. But try to understand this: your outcome can be `["food", "john, 123"]`, or `[["food"], ["john", 123]]`, which are different. Do you see? You need to write a bunch of brackets in your outcome, so people can actually understand what you want.

Comment: It's funny seeing all these people writing answers (six so far!) even if they **don't know** the expected outcome...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an object for collecting all industry grouped items and the iterate the given keys and make an output with the data from the original array.

```js
var array = [{ name: 'john', phone: 123, industry: 'food' }, { name: 'moe', phone: 333, industry: 'feed' }, { name: 'mark', phone: 222, industry: 'food' }],
    groups = {};
    
array.forEach(function (a) {
    groups[a.industry] = (groups[a.industry] || []);
    groups[a.industry].push(a);
});

Object.keys(groups).forEach(function (k) {
    console.log(k);
    groups[k].forEach(function (a) {
        console.log([a.name, a.phone].join(', '));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with [`Array#reduce`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiJyZqJ-pbUAhURTo8KHYpUAB0QFggmMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2FReduce&usg=AFQjCNG5y6qS8juF9mnkgIEZQgeRUeoJ3A&sig2=gaoGcDIP-dalIqpszBoRZw) used for iterate the Array and convert into object  and [`hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) used for find `industry` value is in object or not

```js
var a =[{name: 'john', phone: 123, industry: 'food' }, {name: 'moe', phone: 333, industry: 'feed'},{name: 'mark', phone: 222, industry: 'food'}]
 
 console.log(a.reduce(function(a,b){
if(a.hasOwnProperty(b.industry)){
 a[b.industry].push(b)
 }
 else{
  a[b.industry] =[]
    a[b.industry].push(b)
 }

 return a
 },{}))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const byIndustry = yourArray.reduce((categories, person) => {
   if (!categories[person.industry]) {
     categories[person.industry] = [];
   }

   categories[person.industry].push(person);
   return categories;
}, {});
```

This will result in an object with the available industries as keys and an array of persons of the given industry:

```
{
  food: [{name: 'john'}, {name: 'mark'}]
  ...
}
```